# deploy silent mbam client install

Tags: windows, active-directory, bitlocker

I have a server with mbamserver installed and configured as needed with the group policy's and sql and stuff.

but now i want to roll it out to the clients in my network. i can install the mbamclient.exe via gpo but then the persons need to manually add a password.

so how can i deploy mbamclient on the client pc and automaticly add a password and start drive encryption?
the password needs to depend on the pcname for example btx1177,btx1178 etc.

hope someone can help me

Comment: Have you looked into Mass-Deployment software at all? We use PDQ Delpoy in  our environment and I swear by it. It's super easy to use and ties in with existing Active directory set-ups so you can silently install software via hostname. It uses whatever credentials you give it to install software as well so no user interaction is needed. I will never go back to installing software manually or via GPO. Even the free version of PDQ Deploy is better than that.

Comment: Hi, But i install MBAM PDQ Delploy that way but how can i enable bitlocker using that and automaticly create an password?

Comment: It might take some configuring on your end, but PDQ can deploy scripts as well as software. So if you wanted something to be done with the client after deployment you could add a batch script or a cmd command to the package, along with the software install. i can't really help with the scripting though.